# Passing Data to an AJAX Call

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hey all so Im trying to put data through an AJAX call into this div

```
        <div class="scroll-pane2 blue small" style="">
            <p id="bulletinBodyArea" style="margin-right:20px;"></p>    
        </div>
```

The AJAX is being triggered when one clicks on one of the links being fed from the database

```
        <div class="bulletinSectionAccordion rounded">
            <p class="blue" style="font-size:19px;margin-left:23px;margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:10px;">Archives</p>
        <?php


            $query = "SELECT * FROM `bulletin`  LEFT JOIN `bulletininschool` ON `bulletin`.`id`=`bulletininschool`.`bulletin` WHERE `school` = 2 ";
            $result=$connection->query($query);

          while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            echo  '<p class="medium titi" style="margin-left:23px;">'.$row['title'].'</p>';
          }
        ?>
        </div>
```

It gets called and then passes the data

```
  $(".titi").click(
        getBody
  );

    function getBody(){
      $("#bulletinBodyArea").load('update/getBody.php');
    };
```

And this is the AJAX function

```
<?php
$section='bulletin';
$table="bulletin";
$schoolSelectorTable="bulletininschool";
$schoolSelector="bulletin";

    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_user = "root";
    $db_pass = "";
    $db_name = "isl";


mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
mysql_select_db("isl") or die(mysql_error());


$states = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `bulletin` LEFT JOIN `bulletininschool` ON `bulletin`.`id`=`bulletininschool`.`bulletin` WHERE `school` = 2" );


while($state = mysql_fetch_array($states)){
    echo "<p>".$state['body']."</p>";
}
?>
```

Now the links that one clicks that are fed from the database are actually article titles, and then when one clicks on a specific title the AJAX call should go and fetch the body text associated with that article. But I'm having trouble understanding how I should go through that. I'm doing the correct queries and getting the titles and the bodies but I just cant figure out how to associate them. Do I pass a variable to the AJAX call?

Thank you

Comment: `$(".titi").click(
        getBody
  );` is it the original code or you stripped something?

Comment: put an `alert(1);` or a `console.log(1);` in the `getBody` function and check whether its getting called.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document.ready( function() {
        $(".titi").click( function() { // you had a syntax error here also
             getBody();
        });
  });
  function getBody(){
        $("#bulletinBodyArea").load('update/getBody.php');
  };
```

You had a syntax error in your code it should be getBody(); not only getBody!
Use document ready function!

Comment: It's expected that an answer have an explanation, not just code. Why is the the appropriate answer?